# asp.net onselectedindexchanged method location

Tags: asp.net

In the GridView, why I have to define select method in the same page instead of C# file ?

for example, in the index.aspx, I have

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="index.aspx.cs" Inherits="GridViewApp.index" %>     
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" 
          onselectedindexchanged="GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged" 
        DataSourceID="SqlDataSource2" AllowPaging="True" AllowSorting="True">
            <Columns>
                <asp:CommandField ShowSelectButton="True"  />
            </Columns>
        </asp:GridView>
```

GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged, this method have to be defined in the index.aspx instead of index.aspx.cs ?

The error message is

```
Compiler Error Message: CS1061: 'ASP.index_aspx' does not contain a definition for 'GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged' and no extension method 'GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged' accepting a first argument of type 'ASP.index_aspx' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
```

UPDATED:
resolve. after I clean the project, rebuild it. it works now. what is the correct way to build / debug a project ? how to clean cache ?

Appreciate your help.

Comment: It can be defined in your codebehind if you want it to. The example on msdn just has it all on the aspx page, but that is not required. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.onselectedindexchanged.aspx

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The method `GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged` needs to be defined on the page that contains the `GridView1` and make sure that you declare it at least as `protected`

```
protected void GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   //do magic
}
```

Comment: +1: I was waiting for someone to bring up the access modifier.

Comment: @user595234 then your code behind is not really pointing to the page `.cs` file where you added the method.

Comment: I have a button event, it will go to page .cs file.

Answer (score 1):

Do you have a code behind defined? Are you sure it is being used? At the top of your aspx page, you should have a [page directive](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ydy4x04a.aspx) that looks something like this:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="True" Inherits="The Class Name in index.aspx.cs" Codebehind="index.aspx.cs" %>
```

Once you have your code behind set up, and you are sure it is being used, you need to create an event handler for the [SelectedIndexChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.selectedindexchanged.aspx) event fired on your GridView.

```
protected void GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Response.Write("GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

On aspx page you define which event handler to be called when that particular event occurs and cs file you actually implement the method.

Like in you case: in aspx page you define  that when `SelectedIndexChanged` event fires, `GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged` event handler to be called and in cs file you provide the impementation.